# I'm having a jQuery onclick issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

So I'm going to explain this with an example.

I have a "like" button (class: .like) for my feed or stream. When the user clicks it ( using $(".like") ), it ajaxes it's way to refreshless insert the like into the database (using jQuery).

When it's inserted, I change the text to "Unlike" and the class to ".unlike".

However, when a user reclicks it, it just goes through the same function again, instead of going to the $(".unline").click function. Do I have to "update" the script or something?

For example:

```
    $(".like").click(function(){
       alert("Like!");
       $(this).attr("class", "unlike");
    });
    $(".unlike").click(function(){
       alert("Unlike!");
       $(this).attr("class", "like");
    });
```

The problem is that it won't to the unlike function, it will just repeat the like function even though the attribute is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to make this work:

```
 $(".like").live("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("like").addClass("unlike");
 });
 $(".unlike").live("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("unlike").addClass("like");
 });
```

Comment: just an fyi `live` has been deprecated as of jquery 1.7

Comment: Ditto. use $('parent').on('click', '.childClass', function(){});

Comment: Ugh, live is deprecated? It was the only thing that worked :/

Comment: did you try David's solution?

Comment: @Schart - Yes `live` is deprecated and you should use `on` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The event binding occurs when you assign run the above code. You have to rebind the event every time, or, better yet, use event delegation:

```
$(document)on("click",".like",function(){
   alert("Like!");
   $(this).addClass("unlike");
   $(this).removeClass("like");
});
$(document)on("click",".unlike",function(){
   alert("Unike!");
   $(this).addClass("like");
   $(this).removeClass("unlike");
});
```

Comment: Nope, that broke my code :o. Nothing in console though... Very weird

Answer (score 1):

That is because the "unlike" attr. hasn't been added to the dom when the script loaded. Try this:

```
<body>
<div class="like_it_or_not">
   HELLO!
</div>
</body>
```

And the JS

```
$("body").on('click','.like_it_or_not', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('like', 'unlike');
    if ($(this).hasClass('like')) {
       alert('like');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('unlike')) {
       alert('unlike');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to delegate your click event (which is over-engineering IMO), do a check in the handler:

```
$(".like").click(function(){
   alert( $(this).hasClass('unlike') ? 'unlike' : 'like' );
   $(this).toggleClass("unlike like");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NScyM/

It should check for the 'unlike' class each time you click and toggle classes as expected.

Comment: Best, circumvents all this fussing over event delegation, uses single handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(".like").click(function(){
   alert("Like!");
   $(this).removeClass("like");
   $(this).attr("class", "unlike");
});
$(".unlike").click(function(){
   alert("Unlike!");
   $(this).removeClass("unlike");
   $(this).attr("class", "like");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep my code clean on stuff like this, I assign a class that never changes and tie the click event to that. The styling classes simply act as CSS changes. For instance:

```
<button class="vote like">button text</button>

$('.vote').click(function () {
    var alertText = ($(this).hasClass('like')) ? 'Like!' : 'Unlike!';
    alert(alertText);
    $(this).toggleClass('like').toggleClass('unlike');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
   alert("Like!");
   $(this).html('Unlike').removeClass("like").addClass("unlike");
});

$(document).on('click', '.unlike', function(){
   alert("Unlike!");
   $(this).html('Like').removeClass("unlike").addClass("like");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VU37w/1/).

Comment: I downvoted because the solution given is much more complicated than it needs to be, considering the question. Also, it will have unexpected results if the DOM contains other elements with the same classNames. So, IMHO, this is not an ideal solution, even if it "works".

Comment: @David, OP needs two different handlers for two classes so it's given in that way, anyways, if (according to you) this is a complicated answer then it doesn't mean you should down vote because it's working in it's current state of question, may be you could have just commented, because it's still now a right answer.

Comment: @SheikHeera why would he need two different handlers? It’s the same element, thus only one handler is needed.

Comment: @David, Because he stated it in his question with two different handlers.

Answer (score -1):

The `unlike` click event handler has not been associated with the new item. If you're going to be changing the class dynamically like that you're going to want to look at the (jQuery `on` handler)[http://api.jquery.com/on/]

```
$(document).on('click',".like", function(){
   alert("Like!");
   $(this).addClass("unlike").removeClass('like');

});
$(document).on('click',".unlike",function(){
   alert("Unlike!");
   $(this).addClass("like").removeClass('unlike');
});
```

Comment: [Here is a demo with your code that's not working and it shouldn't](http://jsfiddle.net/mv5C8/).

Comment: This won't bind dynamically to DOM elements. What you have here is the same as .click().

Comment: Sigh, thats what I get for just copy and pasting from the question without paying attention.